# Moving a slide show using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to make a slide show movie automatically, but I want to do it in jQuery. Unfortunately my knowledge is low in jQuery.

This is my HTML:

```
 <div id="smallgal" class="event-carousel owl-carousel">
                            <div class="ec-box">
                                <img src="img/home1/event-banner.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="timer-area">
                                    <div data-countdown="2017/10/16"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ec-box">
                                <img src="img/home1/event-banner.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="timer-area">
                                    <div data-countdown="2017/10/1"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="ec-box">
                                <img src="img/home1/event-banner.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="timer-area">
                                    <div data-countdown="2017/10/30"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please show the script, which you currently have, which didn't work. Others can easily improve from that on and you can point out your mistakes.

Comment: okay here is the thing in css there is a transform from one slide to another like from slide to another like  slide one transform: translate3d(-2017px, 0px, 0px); and in slide 2 transform: translate3d(-2698px, 0px, 0px); is there a way in qjuery to make auto transform

Comment: Have you looked at [existing codepens](https://codepen.io/sebastien_koss/pen/GjRmZB)?

Comment: @rawandferyad you can use CSS as you suggested or you can use jQuery Animate along with other items. It really depends on what you want the carousal or slide show to do. Basically, you are "showing" one image and then sliding it out of the viewport (or offscreen) and sliding the next image into view. You could animate the `width` of each from 100% to 0% or move it's left margin in a negative manner. lots of methods.

Comment: could you give me one example please but the silde should move from left to right

Comment: Hi Rawand. I see you signed in four hours ago today (12th April 2018) and yet have not found the time to reply/vote/accept on the answers below, now a couple of weeks old. Doing so is not strictly mandatory, but it is polite to do so, and if no-one replied, then Stack Overflow would soon cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is so simple,you can slide show move automatically

- Iterate your all images in your div
- Use Setinterval method to fade In    and fade Out Images.

  ```
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  setInterval(function() { 
  $('#slideshow > div:first')
  .fadeOut(1000)
  .next()
  .fadeIn(1000)
  .end()
  .appendTo('#slideshow');
  },  3000);
  ```

  My fiddle:[Jquery move automatically slide show](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerAhmed/r6n79dhj/7/)

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, there are literally so many ways to do this, I cannot describe it. If you want a basic slide show, where an image slides off from right to left, there are some simple methods to do this. In your OP, you did not mention if you wanted this on timing or on an event, lick `click`, to trigger the next image. So in future posts, you have to be MUCH MORE SPECIFIC.

Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

You also did not post any JavaScript or jQuery code to assist you with, another faux pas for Stack Overflow.

Here is an example you could consider. It accomplishes the following:

- Uses HTML `<div>` elements to wrap images are ordered for the carousel
- Moves to next slide on `click` event for Next and Back indicators
- Basic `slide` easing from right to left on screen

```js
$(function() {
  $(".back, .next").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(this);
    if (target.hasClass("next")) {
      var l = $(".slide-wrapper").css("margin-left");
      l = parseInt(l.slice(0, -2));
      var w = $(".ec-box").eq(0).width();
      $(".slide-wrapper").animate({
        marginLeft: (l - w) + "px"
      }, "fast");
    }
    if (target.hasClass("back")) {
      var l = $(".slide-wrapper").css("margin-left");
      l = parseInt(l.slice(0, -2));
      var w = $(".ec-box").eq(0).width();
      $(".slide-wrapper").animate({
        marginLeft: (l + w) + "px"
      }, "fast");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.widget-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

span.back {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

span.next {
  margin-top: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 350px;
}

.event-carousel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px 40px;
}

.event-carousel .ec-box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="widget-wrapper">
  <span class="back ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-w" title="Previous Slide"></span>
  <div id="smallgal" class="event-carousel owl-carousel">
    <div class="slide-wrapper">
      <div class="ec-box">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x280/fcc/fff.jpg&text=Image+1" alt="">
        <div class="timer-area">
          <div data-countdown="2017/10/16"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ec-box">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x280/cfc/fff.jpg&text=Image+2" alt="">
        <div class="timer-area">
          <div data-countdown="2017/10/1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ec-box">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x280/ccf/fff.jpg&text=Image+3" alt="">
        <div class="timer-area">
          <div data-countdown="2017/10/30"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="next ui-icon ui-icon-caret-1-e" title="Next Slide"></span>
</div>
```